# Find the distinct values in array of field, count them and write to another collection as array of string

Tags: mongodb

Is is possible to get the distinct values of field that is an array of strings and write the output of distinct to another collection. As shown below from src_coll to dst_coll.

src_coll

```
{"_id": ObjectId("61968a26c05149a23ad391f4"),"letters": ["aa", "ab", "ac", "ad", "aa", "af"] , "numbers":[11,12,13,14] }
{"_id": ObjectId("61968a26c05149a23ad391f5"),"letters": ["ab", "af", "ag", "ah", "ai", "aj"] , "numbers":[15,16,17,18] }
{"_id": ObjectId("61968a26c05149a23ad391f6"),"letters": ["ac", "ad", "ae", "af", "ag", "ah"] , "numbers":[16,17,18,19] }
{"_id": ObjectId("61968a26c05149a23ad391f7"),"letters": ["ae", "af", "ag", "ah", "ai", "aj"] , "numbers":[17,18,19,20] }
```

dst_coll

```
{"_id": ObjectId("61968a26c05149a23ad391f8"),"all_letters": ["aa", "ab", "ac", "ad", "ae", "af", "ag", "ah", "ai", "aj"] }
```

I have seen the answer using distinct:

`db.src_coll.distinct('letters')` and using aggregate (if collection is huge, because i was getting error `Executor error during distinct command :: caused by :: distinct too big, 16mb cap`). I used:

`db.src_coll.aggregate([ { $group: { _id: "$letters" } }, { $count: "letters_count" }], { allowDiskUse: true })` 
I do no know how to write the output of `distinct` or aggregate as show in dst_coll.

My collection contains 522 documents, Total Size = 314 MB, but the field `letters` contains thousands of string values in array for each document.

I appreciate your time to reply.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method I

I am assuming you are trying to create a single document containing all the distinct values in letters field across all documents in src_col. You can create a collection based on aggregation output using either [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) or [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/). But $out would replace your collection if it already exists.
The unwinding array here would run out of memory in which case you will have to use `{ allowDiskUse: true }` option.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$letters"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      all_letters: {
        "$addToSet": "$letters"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $merge: {
      into: "dst_coll"
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cyIltcCIvZU)

### Method II

Another way to do this without $unwind is to use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) function which is more efficient.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      all_letters: {
        "$addToSet": "$letters"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "all_letters": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$all_letters",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $setUnion: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $merge: {
      into: "dst_coll"
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3A-S1arh56B)

### Method III

Since we are going to create a single document from a collection using group, for large collections it's likely to run into memory issues. A way to avoid this would be to break down grouping into multiple stages, so each stage would not have to keep in memory lot of documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$letters"
  },
  {
    $bucketAuto: {
      groupBy: "$_id",
      buckets: 10000, // adjust the bucket size so that it outputs multiples documents for a range of documents. 
      output: {
        "all_letters": {
          "$addToSet": "$letters"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $bucketAuto: {
      groupBy: "$_id",
      buckets: 1000,
      output: {
        "all_letters": {
          "$addToSet": "$all_letters"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "all_letters": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$all_letters",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $setUnion: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      all_letters: {
        "$addToSet": "$all_letters"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "all_letters": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$all_letters",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $setUnion: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $merge: {
      into: "dst_coll"
    }
  }
])
```

Refer to [$bucketAuto](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucketAuto/) and [Aggregation Pipeline Limits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/).

---

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4KYQmnuUxpZ)

Comment: Thanks. But i get following error:
`MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $addToSet used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes`

Comment: Check if any of the methods works for you.

Comment: I appreciate your time an effort to write the above reply showing methods. For both Method-II and Method-III, i am using `{allowDiskUse:true}`, and `buckets:1000` but still getting the same error, `MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $addToSet used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes`. My collection contains 522 documents, Total Size = 314 MB, but the field `letters` contains thousands of string values in array for each document.

Comment: I think for now quick work around would be to use `db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes: newLimit})` and increase memory limit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution for it but I'm not sure if it's the optimal way.

Algorithm:

1. Unwind all the array
2. Group by letters which will give only unique results
3. Group them again to get a single result

Use the `$out` stage to write the result to another collection:

Aggregation pipeline:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      letters: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$letters"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$letters"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      allLetters: {
        "$addToSet": "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $out: "your-collection-name"
  }
])
```

Kindly see the docs for `$out` stage yourself.

See the solution on mongodb playground: [Query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xsRC-48e1J5)

Comment: Thanks. Your query works. But i get the very same error as mentioned in above comment. `MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $addToSet used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes`